# Command line not displaying Computer name

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I was hoping someone could tell me why I can getting an odd sequence of numbers and letters usually where my computer name is within the terminal. I have checked to naming on the computer (System Preferences > Sharing), which is reading " Medeiros Macbook Pro." Rather than getting this though I get the following within the terminal:

```
Last login: Wed Jul  6 10:23:49 on ttys000
ACA80A7A:~ medeiros$ "
```

Similarly, when I use git log, I get information about the author as "medeiros@ACA80A7A.ipt.aol.com". Any information on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please see what makes a [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in stack overflow.

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the `ACA80A7A` bit? It's most likely a host name set by a DHCP client.

Comment: Your main prompt is controlled by environment variable `PS1`.  The output of `echo "$PS1"` contains what we would need to know to give a confident answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I get the following output " \h:\W \u\$  "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments you reported that your prompt string (`$PS1`) is "`\h:\W \u\$`".  Each digraph consisting of a backslash (`\`) followed by another character is a code representing a piece of information about your machine and environment; the remaining characters represent themselves.  The meaning of the codes is covered in [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt); the ones relevant to you are:

- `\h`: the first segment of the hostname
- `\W`: the basename of the working directory, except that your home directory is abbreviated as a tilde (`~`)
- `\u`: your username
- `\$`: a `#` if your effective user id is `0` (root's), otherwise a `$`

Thus, the "odd sequence" you asked about, evidently "ACA80A7A", is the first segment of the hostname of your computer.  This is also evident in the email address you presented.

If your `PS1` has not changed but your prompt has, then your machine's hostname has changed.  This very likely arises from turning on network autoconfiguration (i.e. DHCP), just as @chepner suggested in comments.